# How to change sample rate in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Im a complete beginner in Unity so sorry if similar question is already exists.
Trying to make 2D platformer watching tutorail and cant find how to change sample rate in animation.
This option doesnt exist in 2019.2.18 by default.

Answer (score 4):

You should click show sample rate, like shown in the image below:

[image]

Here is complete answer link:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-cant-find-animation-sample-value-in-the-gui.686641/

Answer (score 2):

Unity 2019.3.0f3, I believe it exists in your Unity version as well.

`Window -> Animation -> Animation` or `Ctrl + 6` default shortcut. To edit it, the animation or animator containing animation should be selected.

[image: Animation Window Example, sample rate]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Seems like it was switched off by default, but I found how to add in top right corner of animation.